# preg_match Two Letters, Five Numbers, Two Letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am god awful at regular expressions, I just don't understand them and I would appreciate the help of anyone who does.

I need to be able to match two A-Z characters, then five 0-9 characters then two A-Z characters. An example would be `AB12345CD`.

I got this to match five numbers `(^[0-9]{5}$)` but just duplicating this doesn't work, and I feel really stupid for not being able to figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? Check if a string conforms the expression? Find such strings in some longer text?

Comment: @thg435 That's what regex does - match /expression/ in /text_to_search/ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then try this:

```
(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}$)
```

Comment: @thg435 He referred to what he got with brackets, so I assumed he calls this in some method or sth.

Comment: Nope, that crashed CodeIgniter with no errors shown, just a server error. =/

Comment: @AlexMcCabe And the code you posted: (^[0-9]{5}$) works without an error?!

Comment: Yeah it does, validates fine.

Comment: @AlexMcCabe Then we probably need some more context code to figure this out.

Comment: OK, the crashing was my fault. Forgot a semi-colon (god damnit), and now it validates. Thank you! =] I had tried many formats of this, but not this itself. This will be my answer.

Comment: @mpaepper This is correct now, I was trying wrong versions of this regular expression which was causing errors, coupled with the rookie mistake of a forgotten semi-colon. Gah.

Answer (score 8):

simplest to understand, longest to write

```
[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]
```

shorter:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}
```

complete lines only:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}$    // ^ - start of line; $ - end of line
```

capture in parens:

```
(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}$)  // as per mpaepper, for reuse in matched expression
```

shorter still:

```
(^[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]{2}$)     //  \d represents 0-9
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{2}
```

Here is a break down of the expression:

```
[A-Z]    # Match a single character present in the list below
               # A character in the range between “A” and “Z”
   {2}         # Exactly 2 times
[0-9]       # Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9”
   {5}         # Exactly 5 times
```

Or you can try as follow

`[A-Z]{2}\d{5}[A-Z]{2}`

Hope it will help.

Comment: OP does not ask for lowercase.

Comment: This helps break it down for me. What is the \d?

Comment: \d represents any of [0-9]

Comment: `\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9). An alternative for [0-9].

Comment: Ahh, that's useful to keep in mind. How the hell does anyone learn this. Haha. Thanks for your help.